# Splitting tasks using Prefect

Tags: python, prefect

I need to create a batch that can process tasks with this workflow:

```
                                             | task 4
                                  | task 3 ->| task 4
                       | task 2 ->           | task 4
                           
                                  | task 3 ->| task 4
    input ->  task 1 ->
                       | task 2 -> ...
```

- Task #1 processes input data and returns a list of lists.
- Task #2 receives the list from task #1 and also returns a list of lists.
- Task #3 receives the list from task #2 and also returns a list of lists.
- Task #4 receives the list from task #4 and processes data in the list.

For example, task #1 returns `[[],[],[],[]]`. It means flow must run 4 task #2 in parallel. Each task #2 returns `[[],[],[]]`. Now we must have 4x3 task #3. Then task #3 returns `[[],[]]`. Finally flow must run 4x3x2 tasks #4.

Is it possible to do using Prefect Flow? I tried to use mapping functionality but it seems does not support such complicated workflow schema (or perhaps I do not use it properly).

```
with Flow('test') as flow:
   res1 = task1()
   res2 = task2.map(res1)
   res3 = task3.map(res2)
   res4 = task4.map(res3)
```

When I run the flow task1 returns the correct number of lists. Then flow creates 4 task2 and each of them returns the list of three lists. But instead of creating 12 task3, the flow creates only 4 of them.
Each task3 receives the list of 4 lists as it was created with task1 instead of 1 list from task2.

Any ideas about how can I create such a workflow?

Comment: [This issue on Prefect](https://github.com/PrefectHQ/prefect/issues/1874) may be related to your problem. Quoting the dev @cicdw from the link, "Prefect tries to avoid assuming user intent, so will only map over the iterable you provide without changing its contents". I don't use Prefect so I can't give anymore info besides trying it myself.

Comment: Have you looked at using `flatten` ?  I can't say for sure but it seems like what you're looking for: https://docs.prefect.io/core/concepts/mapping.html#flat-mapping

Comment: @chriswhite Thanks a lot, exactly what I needed. It works now with flatten.